# Spring AOP @AfterThrowing not working properly, error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am defining the `@pointcut` expression like below.

```
@Pointcut(
        "execution(* com.xyz..*(..)) && " +
        "!within(is(EnumType)) && " +
        "!within(is(FinalType))"
    )
protected void loggingOperation() {

}
@Before("loggingOperation()")
    public void logEntry1(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Entering " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName() + " ##### "
                + joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), joinPoint.getArgs());
    }

    @After("loggingOperation()")
    public void logExit1(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Exiting " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName() + " ##### "
                + joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), joinPoint.getArgs());

    }

     @AfterThrowing("loggingOperation()")
     public void logException1(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {
     logger.log(Level.SEVERE,
     joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName() + " ##### " +
     joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), e);
     }
```

it returns error saying:

```
 Error creating bean with name 'resourceDataSource' defined in class path resource [resource-dataSource-dbcp-beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at
```

The above code works fine if I remove `@AfterThrowing` so now the problem is with `@AfterThrowing`.

The earlier problem got solved after I removed aspectjrt-1.6 jar from `shared\lib`

Comment: I doubt that *def is not support by AspectJ. I guess you want to create a pointcut for any public method startProcess() of class ending def in package com.xyz() or sub-package. Try to seperate that to smaller pointcut

Comment: It is working in `@Before` and `@After` as expected.

Comment: `formal unbound in pointcut` happens when you have a parameter in the pointcut method. You should bind it in pointcut using `args` for instance: `execution(* method(..)) && args(param1)`. Your example shows no parameters though. Are you sure you are posting the problematic pointcut definition and not some other definition that is correct? Your last example should read: `execution(...) && within(...) && within(...)`. You try to put within in execution which is not legal I think.

Comment: The thing which I do not understand is that the same expression is working in `@Before` and `@After`, if an expression is written bad it shouldn't work at all. In the last example, I just tried one of the solutions found on SO, just to see if it works or not.

Comment: Try your pointcut example one more time. It works fine on my environment.

Comment: Which one of them? Which particular one is running fine on your system?

Comment: @MichałGrzejszczak just checked once again `@AfterThrowing` is the one which is causing it to fail I guess, `@Pointcut("execution(public * com.xyz..*.abc.*def.startProcess(..))")` is working with `@Before` and `@After` but when I add `@AfterThrowing` this:- `error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut ` is thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `Throwable e` parameter in `@AfterThrowing`. Use `throwing` attribute of the annotation:

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "loggingOperation()", throwing = "e")
public void logException1(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {
  ...
}
```